# Actionscript-3 URLLoader: ProgressEvent doesn't dispatch

Tags: actionscript-3

I upload some data to my server with the help of URLLoader, and I listen to the ProgressEvent, but it doesn't dispatch. No errors, files get uploaded successfully. Why could it not work?

Code as follows:

```
//setup
urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);

//listen
private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace(e.bytesLoaded + ' ' + e.bytesTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this answer, but seeing as how I just ran into it myself, I thought I'd add my two cents:

The reason you are not seeing any progress events for a POST/upload is because the URLLoader doesn't dispatch progress events (or change the "bytesLoaded" property) for uploads. Sad, but true.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show when you're actually calling the load() method. It should be :

```
 //setup
 urlLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
 urlLoader.load( new URLRequest( url ) );


 //listen
 private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    trace(e.bytesLoaded + ' ' + e.bytesTotal);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I presume the urlLoader is a loader object instance? If so you need to add the eventListener to the contentLoaderInfo property.

```
urlLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
```

Comment: aesphere, that urlLoader is an instance of the URLLoader class, and it seems there's a bug in it...

Comment: URLLoader doesn't inherit from the Loader class, it inherits from EventDispatcher

Comment: Well my bad, sort of difficult to see what instances are being used when the initial instantiation isn't shown, although I guess I could have taken the hint from urlLoader. That being said tho, some ppl do tend to name their loader instance variables as urlLoader sometimes...